# How to get separated audio channel from 5.1 video with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, stream, converters

I have a video file with audio stream:

```
 Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
 Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 448 kb/s
```

And I can do mixdown it to two-channel audio:

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -map 0:2 -acodec libmp3lame -y output.mp3
```

> Update

It can be splitted by the channelsplit command, but it splits the Stream #0:1 by default and I can't specify Stream #0:2 channel.

```
./ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -vn -filter_complex 'channelsplit=channel_layout=5.1[FC]' -map '[FC]' front_center.mp3
```

How do I specify Stream #0:2 5.1 channel and get separated front center channel from this video?

Comment: `-filter_complex '[0:2]channelsplit=...`

Comment: @Gyan thanks! you can post an answer